# Load external swf into bytearray with adobe flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, arrays

How can I load external swf into bytearray with adobe flash AS3..
Here is my code..

```
var my_url1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("SWF/Lesson1.swf");
my_url1.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
my_url1.contentType = "application/x-shockwave-flash";

var urlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(my_url1);

var myByteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
urlloader.data = myByteArray;
```

It not works well. But it isn't give any error. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should listen for `COMPLETE` event and set the data format to `BINARY`:

```
    var my_url1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("SWF/Lesson1.swf");
    var urlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(my_url1);
    urlloader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void
    {
        var myByteArray:ByteArray = URLLoader(event.target).data as ByteArray;
        trace(myByteArray.length);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you fsbmain, Dear how can I load FLV file using this method..?

Comment: The same if you need only bytes. For play back take a look on the _Video_ and _NetStream_ classes for the simple video display or UI components (like _FLVPlayBack_ from the _FlashPro_) for more complex video player.